# Can we highlight the Action Buttons in notification bar in android?

Tags: java, android, ios, android-studio, oop

[image]

As you can see, I have three *.addAction()* [Busy, Meeting, Driving],
If I am clicking on any one of the action button, I am made a TOAST but I want that if I click on any one of the button, I want it to be highlighted in some way, and when I click another action button, I want the old clicked button to get unhighlighted and new one to get highlighted.
Is there a way to do it? Please help, I have been trying since a week, nothing useful I could find.

I have a class(myservices.java) where I am starting my service and the notification, this is myservices.java ->

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //To open the MainActivity onClick
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Intent busy = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    Intent driving = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    Intent meeting = new Intent(this, InterceptCall.class);
    busy.putExtra("mode","busy");
    driving.putExtra("mode", "driving");
    meeting.putExtra("mode", "meeting");
    PendingIntent busyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, busy, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar
    PendingIntent drivingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, driving, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar
    PendingIntent meetingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, meeting, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //For mini icon in notification bar

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Smart Mode is on ")
            .setContentText("Drag down to display modes.")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setColor(Color.MAGENTA)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pingedlogo)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Busy", busyIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Driving", drivingIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Meeting", meetingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

and this is where I Intercepting calls, InterceptCalls.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String mode = intent.getStringExtra("mode");
    Log.i(TAG, "Mode in start : "+mode);
    if(mode!=null)
    {
        Constant.modeGet = mode;
        Toast.makeText(context, Constant.modeGet.toUpperCase()+" mode is on!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Constant modeGet in start : "+Constant.modeGet);
    }

    InterceptCall IC = new InterceptCall();
    try
    {
```

So, my question is, I have a switch (togggle button) which when I turn on! will start my service and will start a notification (foreground service), in notification I have 3 addAction() -> When I click on any one of the action button, the value is passed to InterceptCall.java variable called String mode. So when a user click on any mode, they will get a TOAST Constant.modeget+" is turned ON!" -> example [BUSY mode is turned ON!].

So I want a way where I can highlight the selected addAction button or a way I can update my notification with a test ---> "MODE" is running. (Next to notification text) So that I know what mode I selected.

Comment: Include your code with the post.

Comment: Show what did you tried...else no one will able to help you.

Comment: @Ashish, I added my code, please check and see if you can understand.

Comment: @user1850484 I have added the code, please let me know if you need any understanding.